# GTK+ App process not killed

Tags: gtk, glade, gtk2

I have GTK+ working in a vs2010 c++ windows app.
It uses the builder to load a gui template from glade.

However when I close the window using the cross icon or right click close at the taskbar,
the process for my app is not killed.

How do I ensure that the process is killed nicely?

Answer (score 2):

Closing the window does not kill the process unless you set up a callback that quits the Gtk+ main loop on the window delete event. Application will exit only after you call `gtk_main_quit()` which terminates the mainloop.

Don't know how the C++ binding to GTK+ works, but in C it would be something like this (taken from [GNOME website](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/c39.html#SEC-HELLOWORLD)):

```
int main( int   argc,
          char *argv[] )
{    

    GtkWidget * window;

    gtk_init (&argc,&argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    g_signal_connect (window, "delete-event",
                  G_CALLBACK (delete_event), NULL);

    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy",
                  G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show (window);

    gtk_main ();
}
```

And then the callbacks:

```
static gboolean delete_event( GtkWidget *widget,
                              GdkEvent  *event,
                              gpointer   data )
{
    g_print ("delete event occurred\n");

    return FALSE;
}

static void destroy( GtkWidget *widget,
                     gpointer   data )
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}
```